# How to read a Image file selected by user using JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage, jfilechooser

I want to read the image selected by user using JFileChooser and then be able to get the color Channels(R,G,B) and the width and height of the image.

Is this the right approach to read the selected image file.

```
File im1 = new File(chooser.getSelectedFile(), null);       
BufferedImage buff =ImageIO.read(im1);
```

Or is there a better way to read the image file in order to get the values of its separate      color channels and get its separate values.

Comment: Shouldn't you read the filepath?

Comment: Thank you Lenymm, I can use the absolute path of the selected image and then create the File object

Comment: Ok, I have changed my vote for up then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks okay. Just keep going with width, height and RGB.

```
File im1 = chooser.getSelectedFile();    
BufferedImage buff = ImageIO.read(im1);

if (buff != null) {
    System.out.println(buff.getWidth() + " " + buff.getHeight());
    System.out.println(buff.getRGB(0, 0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any 'better' way to load the image so I believe you're doing it right.

To answer your whole question, here's an example how to get specific color channels out of the image.

```
Color c = new Color(image.getRGB());
int red = c.getRed();
int green = c.getGreen();
int blue = c.getBlue();
```